# Should I be creating multiple controllers or multiple update methods in one controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

**Issue:** I have a controller where I want to separate the update action into 3 separate update actions... Update for all params (minus the other update actions), update for changing order status (created, cancelled, charged), and an update for charging (charges only occur once a file is uploaded to the order)

**Question:** Can you help direct and guide me in which route i should be going in to accomplishing this?

How should i go about doing this in the most efficient and "right" way?

1. Should i create 2 more controllers (since i need 3 updates), one for changing order status, and one for charging and have them inherit the OrderController?
2. Or is there a way to have 3 update actions in one controller? I tried this, but couldn't figure it out

Here is how I "solved" it, but it doesn't seem to run too smoothly as sometimes i notice when i upload a file to the order, it starts looping and/or takes longer than just having it all under one defined param method:

```
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @order.update(order_status)
        if user_signed_in?
          format.html { redirect_to ([@user, @order]), notice: 'Order was successfully order_status.' }
          format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @order }
        else
          format.html { render :edit }
          format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end
        if @order.update(order_charge)
          @amount = (@order.order_price).to_i * 100
          @amount_seller = (@order.order_price).to_i * 75
          if @order.update(order_charge)
            if current_user.seller?
                          charge = Stripe::Charge.create({
                            :amount      => @amount,
                            :description => 'Rails Stripe customer',
                            :currency    => 'usd',
                            :customer => @order.stripe_customer_token,
                            :destination => {
                              :amount => @amount_seller ,
                              :account => (@order.seller.stripe_token),
                            }
                          })
              @order.order_status = "charged"
              format.html { redirect_to ([@user, @order]), notice: 'Order was successfully uploaded.' }
              format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @order }
            else
              format.html { render :edit }
              format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
            end
          end
        end
        if @order.update(order_params)
          if user_signed_in?
            format.html { redirect_to ([@user, @order]), notice: 'Order was successfully updated.' }
            format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @order }
          else
            format.html { render :edit }
            format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
          if buyer_signed_in?
            format.html { redirect_to ([@user, @order]), notice: 'Order was successfully updated.' }
            format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @order }
          else
            format.html { render :edit }
            format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end
    end


  private

    def set_order
      @order = Order.find(params[:id])
    end


    def order_params
      params.require(:order).permit(:name, :email, :image, :video, :description)
    end

    def order_status
      params.require(:order).permit(:order_status)
    end

    def order_charge
      params.require(:order).permit(:video)
    end
...
end
```

This technically works, but not exactly fast or how i want it to.  When i upload a video, it gives me the order_status message, which is because i change the order status when a video gets uploaded.  But it still works in the sense that a charge is created.

Has anyone ever made an app where they needed multiple update actions under one controller and model and found the best way to go about doing it?

Even though the above code "works", i was told it was not efficient and I should create 2 more controllers to go about what i want to do.  I figured I would come here before i divulge in doing that to get other peoples opinions based on their experience if they have had similar apps with this issue.

Or maybe aside from the above 1 and 2, you have more ideas?

(The update action above isn't complete, such as the order_status.  But I'm mostly concerned on how I should actually go about doing this.)

Answer (score 1):

One way to approach this would be to just have one `order_params` method and remove `order_charge` and `order_status` because whatever the case only one resource is being updated. And as you said the user is charged only in one case when file is uploaded, so instead have a helper method in the **controller** that would be responsible to charge the user.

```
def charge_amount
    @amount = (@order.order_price).to_i * 100
    @amount_seller = (@order.order_price).to_i * 75
    if current_user.seller?
      charge = Stripe::Charge.create({
                        :amount      => @amount,
                        :description => 'Rails Stripe customer',
                        :currency    => 'usd',
                        :customer => @order.stripe_customer_token,
                        :destination => {
                          :amount => @amount_seller ,
                          :account => (@order.seller.stripe_token),
                        }
                      })
      @order.order_status = "charged"
    end
end
```

And inside your update method just update the order and charge the user if required. It would be something like,

```
def update
  respond_to do |format|
    if user_signed_in? #this could be moved to a `before_action` that authenticates the user
      if @order.update(order_status)
        if order_params[:video].present?
          charge = charge_amount
        end
        format.html { redirect_to ([@user, @order]), notice: 'Order was successfully order_status.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @order }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

With this approach the code would shrink in size and separates the logic and would be easier to debug. I hope this answers your question or atleast provide you some guidance.

**update**
If you want separate actions, just create three methods in your controller and depending upon the type of params call the appropriate method in your `update` action.

Comment: this looks like this should work.......so try putting the "charge_amount" action in the orders_helper.rb ? just to clarify make sure im understanding this correctly.  As for .(order_status) - should i just use order_params at that point and put videos on there? -----

Comment: by helper i mean make another method in the controller, and yes remove (order_status) and (order_charge), just use (order_params). i will also update the answer.

Comment: okay so that worked... my only issue now is that.  I want a separate action for each update.  There will be 3 possible update by either a seller or buyer.   Updating order information (name, email, etc.), updating order_status (1,2,3), and Updating by uploading a video.  I want a different message for each.  Whenever I upload a video, i get the order_status message since i change the order status on video upload

Comment: Yes, i ended up creating a new restful under routes and use that route within the same edit page to upload the videos.  I will update my answer

Comment: just added to it.  i found a SO post that was trying to do something similar to me and it ended up working out perfectly.  Apparently you can't separate update actions without more restful actions (whatever they're called) - unless you make another controller, which may not be needed in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this... thanks to a SO post i found earlier...

Orders controller: (separate from update action:)

```
def charge_update
    respond_to do |format|
      @amount = (@order.order_price).to_i * 100
      @amount_seller = (@order.order_price).to_i * 75
      if @order.update(order_charge)
                      charge = Stripe::Charge.create({
                        :amount      => (@order.order_price).to_i * 100,
                        :description => 'Rails Stripe customer',
                        :currency    => 'usd',
                        :customer => @order.stripe_customer_token,
                        :destination => {
                          :amount => @amount_seller ,
                          :account => (@order.seller.stripe_token),
                        }
                      })
          @order.update_column(:order_status, 2)
          format.html { redirect_to ([@user, @order]), notice: 'Order was successfully uploaded.' }
          format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @order }
        else
          format.html { render :edit }
          format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end
  end
```

routes:

```
 resources :orders do
    member do
      patch :charge_update
      put :charge_update
    end
  end
```

And for the upload in the view:

```
<%= form_for([@listing, @order], :url => charge_update_order_path ) do |form| %>
...
<%= form.file_field :video %>
...
<%= form.submit "Upload", class: "btn btn-success"  %>
```

rest of controller: (private section)

```
private

def order_charge
      params.require(:order).permit(:video, :order_status)
    end
```

Now the uploading video action is separate and works faster.  I haven't done the same for updating the order status to cancel, which i may or may not after doing more testing.  The charging aspect was the most important thing to separate from the rest of the params.